# Run a wilcox function for each row in each group

Tags: r, apply

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
                 country=c("US","UK"),
                 md = runif(10,0,10), 
                 og = runif(10, 0, 10))
```

and want to apply wilcox function in each row to compare md and og in each group and each country.

```
results <- apply(df,1,function(x){
 df <- data.frame(x)
 wres<-wilcox.test(df$md,df$og)
 df$test<-format(wres$p.value,scientific = F)
 })
```

I want to have another column consists of P-value. 
but when I run it it gives me the following error:

```
Error in wilcox.test.default(df$mean_modified, df$mean_original) : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

Comment: To apply it for every row you can do `mapply(function(x, y) wilcox.test(x, y)$p.value, df$md, df$og)` but is this what you want?

Comment: how can I get a new column name p.value in the function that you mentioned

Comment: I have used the following approach to rename it but do you have better option:df1<-data.frame(mapply(function(x, y) wilcox.test(x, y)$p.value, df$mean_md, df$mean_od))
colnames(df1)[1]="p_value"
df2<- cbind(df,df1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mapply` to apply `wilcox.test` for every value and then extract `p.value` from it

```
df$p.value <- mapply(function(x, y) wilcox.test(x, y)$p.value, df$md, df$og)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to learn `apply` myself. It seems you wanted to compare `md` and `og` for each group or country. There are other (better) solutions for this. Here is an exercise of using `apply` family to compare `md` and `og` for each `country`:

```
results <- sapply(levels(df$country), function(x){
  df <- subset(df, country== x)
  wilcox.test(df$md,df$og)$p.value})
results
```

You will get something like:

```
> results
       UK        US 
0.8412698 0.1507937
```